# How to use Cassandra with TDE (Transparent Data Encryption)

Tags: encryption, cassandra, tde

I'm trying to figure out how to use Cassandra with TDE (Transparent Data Encryption) and in which DataStax edition TDE is supported.

I've been going through DataStax documentation and from what I see, TDE is supported only in DataStax Enterprise Edition. Is this correct?

Also, TDE is included on table/column level and is specified when creating new tables, not as some configuration?

Just want to confirm my assumptions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct.

**Transparent Data Encryption is only supported in DataStax Enterprise (since version 3.2)**.

**Transparent Data Encryption is specified when you create/alter a table**

```
ALTER TABLE users WITH compression = { 
  'sstable_compression' : 'Encryptor',
  'cipher_algorithm' : 'AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding',
  'secret_key_strength' : 128,
  'chunk_length_kb' : 1 
  };
```

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/sec/secTDEtblcrypt.html contains the latest documentation about **Transparent Data Encryption in DSE 4.7**

Comment: DataStax Enterprise should be free for usage on development environment? In other words, I should be able to install it on single node and try out cassandra with this option there?

Comment: @BakirJusufbegovic you can download the latest version of **DataStax Enterprise** from https://academy.datastax.com/downloads?destination=downloads&dxt=DX and play around with it (incl **Transparent Data Encryption**).