# TDE for a single table in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm running Apache Cassandra 3.9 (from http://cassandra.apache.org/download/) on my Windows machine. I want to enable encryption on a single table. I'm running my queries using dbeaver tool.

The below query throws an error.

```
alter table config_test
with compression = { 'sstable_compression' : 'Encryptor',
'cipher_algorithm' : 'AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding',
'secret_key_strength' : 128,
'chunk_length_kb' : 1};
```

Error is,

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidConfigurationInQueryException: Could not create Compression for type org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.Encryptor
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidConfigurationInQueryException: Could not create Compression for type org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.Encryptor
```

1. This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584253/how-to-use-cassandra-with-tde-transparent-data-encryption) says TDE is only available in Datastax Enterprise(DE) version. I thought DE is only a driver for Cassandra. Is that not the case?
2. To make TDE work, should I download and run DE version and follow the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/sec/encryptPerTableTDE.html)? If this the way, is DE free/open-source?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. There is both the driver and the cassandra, driver is free but DSE cassandra is free just for development
2. You would need to pay the fees to use it for production

Comment: Datastax provides drivers for cassandra, and also a commercially supported version of Cassandra named DataStax Enterprise (DSE). It has a number of integrations not available in community Cassandra.